# Union of 2 active record relation object in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a content model represented by class: **content**. Now users can *rate content*, *review content* or do both. I want to find all the content that a user have either *rated*, *reviewed* or *rated and reviewed*. The **reviews** table has a many-to-one association with the **content** table (meaning a content can be reviewed many times). A similar relationship exists between the **ratings** table and the **content** table.

I'm thinking I should do separate queries to find all rated content by a user, then all reviewed content by a user, then do a union. But I can't find out how to do a union that returns an active record relation. I need a relation because I want to paginate the results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so first let's set up your models.  From your explanation I'm thinking you'll want something like this:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :reviewing_users, :through => :reviews, :class_name => "User"

  has_many :ratings
  has_many :rating_users, :through => :ratings, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :reviewed_contents, :through => :reviews, :class_name => "Content"

  has_many :ratings
  has_many :rated_contents, :through => :ratings, :class_name => "Content"
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :user
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And then for a given user you can find all the content that they've reviewed and/or rated with:

```
( user.reviewed_contents + user.rated_contents ).uniq
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back. But this worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks to [Robertibiris](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2653957/robertibiris) for pointing out my typo

Answer (score 2):

`(user.reviewed_contents + user.rated_contents).uniq` returns an array, not a relation, so beware.  You can test this by attempting to call a class method on `@posts` (other than paginate).

You can still paginate though.  just use `@posts.paginate`, as the `will_paginate` gem adds a **[paginate](http://pathfindersoftware.com/2008/06/how-to-use-will_paginate-with-non-activerecord-collectionarray/)** method to the array class.